# How to redirect user based on device in node js

Tags: node.js

I am having one issue for redirecting user dynamically based on device in node js application. My scenario is like this ==> If a user try to access my node js application from a mobile device, then i need to redirect user to `res.render('/themes/v1/home')`. other wise need to redirect user to `res.render('/themes/v2/home')`. I thought of using `res.locals` but `res.locals` is only to be used in **views** not inside of **js files** which are having code to redirect user. Kindly Help us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
app.get('/',function(req, res, next){
        var MobileDetect = require('mobile-detect'),
        md = new MobileDetect(req.headers['user-agent']);
        if(md.mobile()){
           res.render('/themes/v1/home'); // this renders view to redirect use res.redirect()
        } else {
             res.render('/themes/v2/home');
        }
     })
```

hope it helps :)